# An identity involving the Beta function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

I'm trying to show that

$$ \int _0^1 \frac{x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{(x+c)^{a+b}}dx = \frac{B(a,b)}{(1+c)^ac^b}$$

Where $$B(a,b) :=  \int _0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx $$ is the "Beta function".  I am supposed to use a substitution but I'm pretty much stuck.  I am familiar with the basic properties of the Beta function, its relation to the gamma function etc.     Any hints or advice you care to offer would be super cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle   \int _0^1 \frac{x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{(x+c)^{a+b}}dx = I$

We have ,

$(1+c)^ac^bI=\displaystyle  \int _0^1 \frac{(1+c)^ac^bx^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{(x+c)^{a+b}}dx $

$=\displaystyle  \int _0^1 \frac{(1+c)c((1+c)x)^{a-1}(c(1-x))^{b-1}}{(x+c)^{a+b}}dx $

$=\displaystyle  \int _0^1 \left(\frac{(1+c)c}{(x+c)^2}\right)\left(\frac{(1+c)x}{(x+c)}\right)^{a-1}\left(\frac{c(1-x)}{(x+c)}\right)^{b-1}dx$

Let $\displaystyle y=\left(\frac{c(1-x)}{(x+c)}\right)$ and we have $\displaystyle dy=-\left(\frac{(1+c)c}{(x+c)^2}\right)dx$

Then we have the above $=-\displaystyle\int _1^0y^{b-1}(1-y)^{a-1}dy=\int_0^1y^{b-1}(1-y)^{a-1}dy=B(b,a)=B(a,b)$

So ultimately we have,

$\displaystyle(1+c)^ac^bI=B(a,b)\Rightarrow I=\frac{B(a,b)}{(1+c)^ac^b}$

Answer (score 6):

let
$$\dfrac{x}{x+c}=\dfrac{1}{1+c}t$$
then
$$\dfrac{c}{(x+c)^2}dx=\dfrac{1}{1+c}dt$$
then
\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{(x+c)^{a+b}}dx&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\dfrac{x}{x+c}\right)^{a-1}\left(\dfrac{1-x}{x+c}\right)^{b-1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(x+c)^2}dx\\
&=\dfrac{1}{c}\dfrac{1}{1+c}\dfrac{1}{c^{b-1}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(1+c)^{a-1}}\int_{0}^{1}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt\\
&=\dfrac{B(a,b)}{(1+c)^ac^b}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Would upvote if I could

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

It appears that I deleted my answer because it was too similar to another answer in this thread. So the following is a different approach.

$ $

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{(x+c)^{a+b}} \ dx &= \frac{1}{c^{a+b}} \int_{0}^{1} x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \left( 1+\frac{x}{c}\right) ^{-(a+b)} \ dx \\ &= \frac{B(a,b)}{c^{a+b}} {}_{2}F_{1} \left(a+b, a;a+b;-\frac{1}{c} \right) \\ &= \frac{B(a,b)}{c^{a+b}} {}_{2}F_{1} \left(a, a+b;a+b;-\frac{1}{c} \right) \end{align}$$

where I used [Euler's integral representation of the hypergeometric function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Integral_formulas)

But $ \displaystyle {}_{2}F_{1} (a, b;b;z)$ is the hypergeometric representation of $(1-z)^{-a}$ ([15.4.6](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4)).

Therefore,

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{(x+c)^{a+b}} \ dx &= \frac{B(a,b)}{c^{a+b}} \left(1+\frac{1}{c} \right)^{-a}\\ &= \frac{B(a,b)}{(1+c)^{a}c^{b}} . \end{align}$$